# Java not releasing unused heap memory

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am facing an issue where my Java application heap increases with an increased no. of requests to the application but then it does not release even the unused heap memory.

Here is the description:

- My java application starts with a heap memory of 200MB out of which around 100MB is in use.
- As the no. of requests increases, the heap memory usage goes up to 1GB.
- Once the requests processing is finished, the used heap memory drops back to normal but the unused/free heap space remains 1GB.

I have tried to use *-XX:-ShrinkHeapInSteps, -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio* and *-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio* JVM arguments but was not able to solve this.

**Note:** If I try to run the Garbage Collector manually then it lowers the unused heap memory also.

Please suggest how we can lower the unused heap memory.

Comment: `the used heap memory drops back to normal but the unused/free heap space remains 1GB.` This sounds normal to me.  In garbage collected systems, the GC doesn't run until it's reasonable to do so.  High load may delay the GC and lack of memory pressure might delay it as well.  It's normal to see the memory usage go way up, then drop back down when the system gets around to GC.  As long as you're not throwing errors you're probably ok.

Comment: Which jvm are you using? [this](https://thomas.preissler.me/blog/2021/05/02/release-memory-back-to-the-os-with-java-11) suggests some options, but I'm not sure if they're relevant for later JVMs

Comment: I am using open jdk 11

Answer (score 0):

The used heap will not return if the `-Xms` is high. `-Xms` essentially overrides the FreeRation. Now there are other factors to consider, in the case of parallel GC you can't shrink the heap as parallel GC doesn't allow that.

Also, JVM can only relinquish the memory after the fullGC if parallelGC is not used.

So essentially, not much can be done here. The JVM doesn't relinquish the memory to OS to avoid recreating the memory. Memory allocation is expensive work, so JVM will hold on to that memory for some time and as the memory management is controlled by Java, it is not always possible to force things here.

One downside of reducing heap size would be, it will take time for Java to recreate the memory space over and over with incoming requests. So the clients will always see some higher latency. However, if the memory space is already created, the next stream of clients will see lower latency so essentially your amortized performance will increase.

Comment: Whether or not the JVM can release memory depends on the specific garbage collector used and the Java version.